# How to get grid using backbone marionnette js

Tags: java, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-framework, marionette

Please help me to achieve the following grid using `backbone.marionnette.js`

```
1. a link to add new row
2. row will have text boxes where the data can be entered.
```

since i am very newbie to backbone.marionette.js, i could not even figure out what to do and where to start with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use a collection view (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md). This will display the same view (called an item view) for each model instance in the collection.

Then, your item view needs to have a matching template that will have text boxes.

Thanks to Marionette's magic, adding a row simply means adding a new model to the collection, either directly:

```
myCollection.create({ name: "foo" });
```

or by adding an existing model:

```
var m = new MyModel({ name: "foo" });
myCollection.add(m);
```

So your "link to add a new row" will simply create a new model and add it to the collection.

Using models and collection views is explained in more detail in the [free sample](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) to my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).

Since you're new to Marionette, you can also learn more by reading my blog posts on the subject: http://davidsulc.com/blog/category/backbone-js/backbone-marionette/

Comment: Thanks David, Please provide some jsfiddle for the above which will help not only me but many. :)